# How do I filter a view by the results of hook_node_access?

Tags: views

I have been trying to wrap my head around a specific problem for a few days now and have been unable to find a solution. Here's my problem:

In my LMS I'm performing pretty complex access checks. (In particular, I need to check permissions over references: A *lesson* should be accessible, if it's part of some *course* that's marked accessible for that specific user.) I have already written a module implementing `hook_node_access` and, so far, everything is working fine. Here's part of the code:

```
function mymodule_node_access(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node, $op, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account){
  $type = $node->bundle();
  $user = $account->getAccount();
  $uid = $user->id();

  // only handle the lesson content type
  if ($type === 'lesson') {

    if ($account->id() !== 1) {

      // first, check the user's access to the lesson itself
      $lessonaccess = ...

      // then, check the user's access to the referring courses
      $courseaccess = FALSE;
      if ($node->hasField('reverse_entity_reference')) {
        $parentcourses = $node->get('reverse_entity_reference')->getValue();

        foreach ($parentcourses as $course) {
          $coursenode = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($course['target_id']);
          // perform access checks for the referring course
          $courseaccess = $courseaccess || ...
        }
      }

      // combine the results; teasers should always be accessible
      if ($lessonisteaser || ($lessonaccess && $courseaccess)) {
        return AccessResult::allowed();
      } else {
        return AccessResult::forbidden();
      }
    }
  }

  else {
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I would now like to create a view listing all lessons that are accessible to the current user. So, simply filtering by node access -- as is straightforward to achieve in Views -- is not sufficient, as I need to **filter by what is returned from the access checks** in `hook_node_access`.

Can anybody think of a way to make that possible? Maybe storing the result somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you need to store the result somewhere. This is the node_access table of the node grants system (part of core), which you then can use to filter nodes in Views. See this great blog post https://www.droptica.com/blog/drupal-node-grants/

Comment: Thank you very much, that link is very helpful, indeed. Frankly, I have never used the grants system before, but can already imagine that it has the potential to be faster than my approach. However... I still fail to understand, how I am to proceed: Can I store the result of `hook_node_access` as a grant somehow? How do the realms come into play? I think, the concept is still a bit unclear to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that hook_node_access is a PHP function that has nodes passed through it, but Views is doing a database query for the relevant nodes. These two are incompatible, as Views would have to fetch every node in the system from the DB, then pass them all through that function, which would add major overhead.

Drupal's solution to this is the node grants system, which writes a set of grants to the {node_access} table, which can then be used in querying nodes.

To implement a grants system, you'll need to implement [hook_node_access_records()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/8.8.x), which is called when each node is saved, and sets up a number of rules by which the node being save is allowed to be accessed. Then you implement [hook_node_grants()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/8.8.x), which generates a set of potential grants for the current user, and tries to match them with the grants created in hook_node_access_records(). When there is a match, the user is granted permission to access, and this will work with DB queries.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That sounds like a viable route. But the grants system is still a bit unclear to me: At what point would the access checks that I defined in `hook_node_access` come into play? Do I rewrite these as rules in `hook_node_access_records`? Or do i call them from `hook_node_grants`?

Comment: hook_node_access() is implemented when accessing a single node. Individual nodes are passed through this function. The grants system is used when requesting nodes from the DB. It's used in DB queries. You probably need/want to use a combination of both of them, but they work independently of each other (ie - you don't call node_access_records(), you rewrite the rules into the node grants system).

Comment: So, to make sure, I understood this correctly... You are suggesting, I rewrite the access checks in my `hook_node_access` as grants in `hook_node_access_records` and then give the user the required grants in `hook_node_grants`, correct? If so, how can I make the grants that a user is given depend on the currently viewed node? I cannot access the node (and its referring nodes) in `hook_node_grants`, can I?

Comment: You'll need to read up on node grants and look at some existing examples to understand how the system is put together. Basically, you put together a template of grants in hook_node_access_records(), and you put together an array of grants in hook_node_grants(), and the system will overlay them to see if there is a match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will read up a bit on the system and report back. Just one more quick question: In my case, a user's access to a specific node depends on that same user's access to another node (referring courses). I can't think of a way to check access in this case by just overlaying two separate arrays of grants... Any idea?

Comment: Play with it for a bit, then open a new issue with more specific questions. I believe the original question, "How do I filter a view by the results of hook_node_access?", has been answered here, and the format of this site is one question-one answer, rather than long discussions.

Comment: I do understand that and will, of course, play around with it myself. But let me add that the system, as I understood it so far, will **not** allow me to cover all I can do with `hook_node_access` (see my example). If I'm wrong, the answer could be improved by at least hinting to a possible solution...

Comment: "Was I understood it so far, will not allow me to cover all I can do with hook_node_access" - I don't see why not. I've never found a situation that couldn't be addressed through the node grants system, and reading yours, I don't see any red flags. But I'd have to write some code and debug it to provide an actual solution, and I've got my own code to write and debug today :)

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's all I needed to know. I'm prepared to write code, I just don't want to waste time trying to find a solution for a use case that the system wasn't intended for. (Admittedly, I'm still unsure, as to how to implement access checks, when none of these two hooks has access to both the user and the node at the same time, but maybe I'll find something...). Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: For a pointer in the right direction: set a simple note grant in hook_node_access_records(). Put your logic into hook_node_grants(). See this thread where I gave a similar type example: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2020-04-17/question-regarding-hook_node_grants

Comment: That'll help, thanks again. (Though, what's still unclear to me: My logic includes checking the referring nodes of the current node, but I don't have access to the current node in `hook_node_grants`... only to data about the user... but maybe I'm still misunderstanding something...)