# How do I implement access checks based on referring nodes in the grants system?

Tags: views, users, hooks, security

Following a suggestion in another thread [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293067/how-do-i-filter-a-view-by-the-results-of-hook-node-access) I'm trying to rewrite the access restrictions that I developed using `hook_node_access` (and that are working well, so far) in Drupal's grant system (i.e. using `hook_node_access_records` and `hook_node_grants`). I would like to do that for two reasons:

1. I'm worried that the current access checks might become a performance bottleneck, when the number of users grows.
2. I need to use the results of access checks as a filter in views.

Here's a truncated version of my current access checks:

```
function mymodule_node_access(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node, $op, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account){
  $type = $node->bundle();
  $user = $account->getAccount();
  $uid = $user->id();

  // only handle the lesson content type
  if ($type === 'lesson') {

    // ...

    // check the user's access to the referring courses
    $courseaccess = FALSE;
    if ($node->hasField('reverse_entity_reference')) {
      $parentcourses = $node->get('reverse_entity_reference')->getValue();
      foreach ($parentcourses as $course) {
        $coursenode = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($course['target_id']);
        // perform access checks for the referring course
        $courseaccess = $courseaccess || ...
      }
    }

    // ...

    // return the result
    if ($courseaccess) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    } else {
      return AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
  }

  // ...

}
```

Note that, in essence, I need to **check, whether the current user has access to any of the nodes (*courses*) that are referring to the viewed node (*lessons*)**: That determines, whether the user may access the *lesson*. I'm using *reverse entity references* for that.

As I see it (I'm open to suggestions), there are fundamentally two ways for approaching this. Unfortunately, so far, I have been unable to solve the problems involved. So, in my understanding, I could...

1. Put (more or less) the full access logic into `hook_node_grants`: That would mean, I need to have access to the currently viewed node (*lesson*) in `hook_node_grants` to be able to follow its reverse references to check, whether the user has access to any of the referring nodes. Is that possible? There's no `$node` variable...
2. Put (more or less) the full access logic into `hook_node_access_records`: In that case, the problem is that the hook only gets called (and thus the *lesson* gets updated), whenever the node is saved. So, the access restrictions will be out of date, as soon as a lesson is included in another *course*.

I'm unsure how to proceed at this point. Is it even possible to rewrite this in the grant system? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Given that we don't have an exhaustive list of requirements & Q&A isn't suited well for long discussions, it will be impossible to definitely say yes.

The grant system isn't designed around any sort idea of hierarchy. Is it possible to rewrite? It depends if you can refactor your existing logic around what the grant system supplies.

You've framed your question as a dilemma, but you really need both hooks to use the grant system:

- `hook_node_grants` need to assign `realm`/`gid` grants that correspond to the `$user` and the available lesson `nid` they can access.
- `hook_node_access_records` needs to fire against a lesson `$node`

So if you can:

- Map the `realm`/`gid` grant keys to match to courses the user has access to (e.g. `mymodule_course_realm`/`123` where `123` some group identifier that maps to a group of users that have course access, thus lesson `nid` access)
- Trigger *lesson* save events upon course updates (e.g. using `hook_node_update`, `hook_node_insert`, etc. to look for update courses, then doing dummy saves on the lesson nodes) so that `hook_node_access_records` can fire against *lesson* nodes that have a changed relationship. (or build custom logic where you insert grants directly via `NodeGrantDatabaseStorage::write()`)

You can probably refactor around the hooks the grant system provides.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I was afraid this might be the bottom line. I had already thought of triggering _lesson_ save events, but am worried that this might cause inefficiencies and inconsistencies down the road. Which is why I was hoping for a way to get access to the `$node` variable in `hook_node_grants`. Sadly, refactoring the system seems unrealistic, as the flexibility is important: I.e., if a _lesson_ is part of two _courses_, only one of which the user may access, the _lesson_ should be accessible in **both** _courses_! Thanks anyway, much appreciated!