# The values returned from hook_node_access_records() aren't considered to allow access

Tags: views, nodes, hooks

I am implementing a solution in Drupal 9 where users are allowed to see only the nodes that belongs to their same group. If a node doesn't belong to any group, t hey should be able to see it.
I've used `hook_node_grants()` to assign the right grants to the current user and `hook_node_access_records()` to set the view grant per node, as suggested in [How do I filter a view by the results of hook_node_access?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293067/how-do-i-filter-a-view-by-the-results-of-hook-node-access)

When visiting a node a user isn't supposed to see, the user gets a 403 error, as expected result. On a view, the node is visible, though.

As workaround, I could implement `hook_views_query_alter()` and add an access condition, but I prefer more generic solution.

This is the code I am using.

```php
 function mymodule_node_access_records(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->hasField('field_group') && !empty($term = $node->field_group->getValue())) {
    $term = reset($term);
    $grants[] = [
      'realm' => 'mymodule_realm',
      'gid' => $term['target_id'],
      'grant_view' => 1,
      'grant_update' => 0,
      'grant_delete' => 0,
      'priority' => 0,
    ];

    return $grants;
  }
}

 function mymodule_node_grants(AccountInterface $account) {
  $grants = [];
  if ($group = checkGroupHelper($account)) {
    $grants['mymodule_realm'] = $group;
  }
  return $grants;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working by adding Query tag **node_access** under my view's Query settings. It started filtering results based on the node_access table. Never seen it as a requirement, so that's a bit strange, but hopefully it can help others wondering like me.